# Berkshelf not working after berks install

Tags: chef-infra, berkshelf, chefdk

I run Berks Install inside my cookbook. So for example let's say I clone Jenkins to my computer and navigate to that cookbook in my chef-repo I get an error. SO after I run it I see all of the dependencies being downloaded however when I go to upload it to my chef server it says I'm missing dependencies. The weird part is that all of the dependencies it's missing are version 0.0.0 cookbooks.

```
Resolving cookbook dependencies...
Fetching 'pipeline' from source at .
Fetching 'pipeline_test' from source 
test/fixtures/cookbooks/pipeline_test 
Using apt (2.9.2)
Using build-essential (2.2.4)
Using chef-dk (3.1.0)
Using chef-zero (2.0.0) from git://github.com/sethvargo-cookbooks/chef-zero.git (at master)
Using chef_handler (1.2.0)
Using dmg (2.3.0)
Using emacs (0.10.0)
Using git (4.3.5)
Using java (1.39.0)
Using jenkins (2.4.1)
Using packagecloud (0.1.1)
Using pipeline (2.3.2) from source at .
Using pipeline_test (0.1.0) from source at    test/fixtures/cookbooks/pipeline_test
Using runit (1.7.6)
Using sudo (2.7.2)
Using windows (1.39.1)
Using yum (3.8.2)
Using yum-epel (0.6.5)

ERROR: The missing cookbook(s) are: 'yum' version '>= 0.0.0', 'git' version     '>= 0.0.0', 'jenkins' version '>= 0.0.0', 'chef-zero' version '>= 0.0.0', 'emacs' version '>= 0.0.0', 'sudo' version '>= 0.0.0', 'chef-dk' version '>= 0.0.0'
```

Then I run the chef upload and I get this

```
Uploading pipeline       [2.3.2]
ERROR: Cookbook pipeline depends on cookbooks which are not currently
ERROR: being uploaded and cannot be found on the server.
```

Berksfile contents

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io' 
metadata 
cookbook 'chef-zero', github: 'sethvargo-cookbooks/chef-zero' 
cookbook 'pipeline_test, path: 'test/fixtures/cookbooks/pipeline_test'
```

Comment: Please include the contents of the `Berksfile` from that directory.

Comment: Can you also show us the exact commands you're using? E.g. `berks install` and `berks upload`?

Comment: Can you also throw up your metadata depends list?